# Facebook login not properly being recognized once returning to app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I'm having trouble implementing the Facebook SDK in an iOS project. I am trying to call it on a specific section of my app through a UIActionSheet. I am able to login to Facebook, but once redirected back to my app, the app does not register that it is logged in and can't execute any of its sharing functions.

I have followed the Facebook iOS Tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ to include adding "fbMY_APP_ID" in the project info but can't figure out why it won't recognize that I am logged in.

Here is the relevant header and method I am using. For convenience, I've removed items unrelated to Facebook implementation:

```
//Header


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "MWFeedItem.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"


@interface DetailTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>{

Facebook *facebook;
BOOL login;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook *facebook;


@end
```

And the method:

```
//  Method

#import "DetailTableViewController.h"
#import "NSString+HTML.h"
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>

@implementation DetailTableViewController

@synthesize facebook;

//Navigation button on detail view does THIS:

- (void)navAction {
    NSLog(@"Action sheet activated.");

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Like this story?" 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"Email link"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Share on Facebook", @"Share on Twitter", @"Open in Safari", nil];

        [actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];

}

-(void)actionSheet: (UIActionSheet *) actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex{

///////THIS SECTION DEFINES THE EMAIL SHARE FUNCTION/////


if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    // MFMailComposeViewController implementation

}


///////THIS SECTION DEFINES THE FACEBOOK SHARE FUNCTION/////

    else {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {

            if (login == NO){

                NSLog(@"No login detected");

                UIAlertView *infoAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Login necessary"
                                          message:@"You must first login to your Facebook account to use this feature." 
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Login" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
                [infoAlert show];
            }else {
                if (login == YES){

                NSLog(@"Login detected.");

                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
                [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationKey"];
                [defaults synchronize];

                //APPLY LOGIN ACTION HERE. Waiting until I can make the system run the NSLog above. So far, the login is not being correctly recorded.

                }
            }


        }

        ///////THIS SECTION DEFINES THE TWITTER SHARE FUNCTION/////

        else {
        if (buttonIndex == 2) {

            //Twitter implementation here                
        }

    ///////THIS SECTION DEFINES THE SAFARI FUNCTION/////


        else{
            if (buttonIndex == 3){

            //Safari implementation here                    
            }

        }
        }   

    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {
            if (buttonIndex == 0)

            {

                // CALL TO FACEBOOK HERE

                facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MY_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]){
                    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
                    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

                }

                if (![facebook isSessionValid]){

                    NSLog(@"Reached isSessionValid evaluation.");

                    [facebook authorize:nil];
                }

            }
            else if (buttonIndex == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Pressed cancel button");


            }
        }

// THIS METHOD SUPPORTS IOS PRE 4.2
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

// THIS METHOD SUPPORTS IOS AFTER 4.2
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}


////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{

}

- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken
           expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt{

}

- (void)fbDidLogout{

}

- (void)fbSessionInvalidated{

}

- (void) fbDidLogin {

    NSLog(@"Logged in with Facebook credentials");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

//APPLY LOGIN ACTION HERE. Waiting until I can make the system run the NSLog above. So far, the login is not being correctly recorded.

}
```

Additional info:

I've also tried adding the openURL portions to the main app delegate file but had the same results.

Comment: Where is your Sharing method? Where you call it?

Comment: I removed it for the time being. All I'm trying to do at the moment is get the app to recognize that it's logged in by watching the NSLog activity. I thought after being logged in and redirected back to the app that the fbDidLogin method should get called. Am I mistaken?

Comment: It will not call fbDidLogin: method everytime. It will call this method, only when there is no token and expiration date in y0ur user defaults or the token and expiration date is invalid in your userDefaults.

Comment: Mr.Evan Dyson, Try to improve your accepted Rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your project. I had a same issues which you have. Now my code is working perfect. Call your `sharing method` in your `fbDidLogin` method too. Dont forget to change your `App id` in code and also `.plist` File.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
            facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        }
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}else{
[self postWall];
}
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self postWall];
}
-(void)postWall{

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/",@"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg",@"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs",@"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation",@"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.",@"description",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",@"message",
                                   nil];

    [[self facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

Comment: This yields the same result. No activity after being redirected back to the app.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your "BOOL login" in your code. You are not changing its value anywhere. So i think it always says NO and getting called alertView and you are not logging in.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to some deprecated Facebook API methods.  See this post for possible help as well:  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843851/arc-project-with-delegate-reference-fails-compiling/9844202#9844202)

Comment: Could be, Brooks. I'm just trying to work through to the solution. That earlier question was me too.

Comment: LOL My bad... If you want I will delete my answer... ;)

Comment: No worries. Appreciate any response.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the way you are presenting and dismissing the action sheet?  iOS 5.x has some new methods and recommendations for handling action sheet presentations.  For example, relying on the action sheet delegate for presentation and dismissal...?